# Has anybody gotten the contact sensor example to work in a repo-installed Gazebo 1.5.0

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As mentioned in my [other question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2062/control-model-tutorial-sensor-isnt-attached/), the [Gazebo tutorial for 1.5.0 on the contact sensor](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/sensors/contact) isn't working for me. I've now tried it on two separate computers -- one of which has a brand new install of Gazebo 1.5.  I've gone up to (and including) the step with `gztopic echo /gazebo/default/box/link/my_contact`.  Nothing shows up.  Not when I move the box around, not when I drag other cubes into it. Nothin'.

I was also having problems with the ray sensor. Andrei said it worked fine on his copy which is installed from source. I'm wondering if this is related.

Has anyone gotten this to work on a repo-installed version of Gazebo 1.5.0?

My output for the gztopic list command (while running contact.world):

```
$ gztopic list
/gazebo/default/pose/info
/gazebo/default/gui
/gazebo/default/log/status
/gazebo/default/response
/gazebo/default/world_stats
/gazebo/default/selection
/gazebo/default/model/info
/gazebo/default/light
/gazebo/default/physics/contacts
/gazebo/default/visual
/gazebo/default/request
/gazebo/default/joint
/gazebo/default/sensor
/gazebo/default/box/link/my_contact
/gazebo/world/modify
/gazebo/default/diagnostics
/gazebo/default/factory
/gazebo/default/model/modify
/gazebo/default/scene
/gazebo/default/physics
/gazebo/default/world_control
/gazebo/server/control
```

and for echoing the topic:

```
$ gztopic echo /gazebo/default/box/link/my_contact
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 142.103.111.179
```

Also, I should mention that echoing the /gazebo/default/diagnostics gives what, I think, is expected:

```
$ gztopic echo /gazebo/default/diagnostics
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 142.103.111.179
real_time {
  sec: 545
  nsec: 278030788
}
sim_time {
  sec: 543
  nsec: 639000000
}
real_time_factor: 0.99699413700000006

real_time {
  sec: 545
  nsec: 279033152
}
sim_time {
  sec: 543
  nsec: 640000000
}
real_time_factor: 0.99699413900000011
...
```

Echoing /gazebo/default/physics/contacts gives:

```
$ gztopic echo /gazebo/default/physics/contacts
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 142.103.111.179
contact {
  collision1: "box::link::box_collision"
  collision2: "ground_plane::link::collision"
  position {
    x: -0.500000000000538
    y: 0.5000000000027871
    z: -1.3116396857526524e-11
  }
  position {
    x: 0.499999999999462
    y: 0.50000000000861855
    z: -1.3116396854834858e-11
  }
  normal {
    x: 0
    y: 0
    z: 1
  }
  normal {
    x: 0
    y: 0
    z: 1
  }
  depth: 1.3116396857526524e-11
  depth: 1.3116396854834858e-11
  wrench {
    body_1_name: "box::link::box_collision"
    body_2_name: "ground_plane::link::collision"
    body_1_force {
      x: -2.3140274425398203e-05
      y: -0.58800230164949263
      z: 2.9400153497970845
    }
    body_2_force {
      x: 0
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
    body_1_torque {
      x: 1.1760044495821824
      y: 1.4700192450579339
      z: 0.29401272095006686
    }
    body_2_torque {
      x: 0
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
  }
  wrench {
    body_1_name: "box::link::box_collision"
    body_2_name: "ground_plane::link::collision"
    body_1_force {
      x: 2.3140281286035522e-05
      y: -0.58800230164948963
      z: 2.940015349797072
    }
    body_2_force {
      x: 0
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
    body_1_torque {
      x: 1.176004449599322
      y: -1.4700192450442133
      z: -0.29401272095006692
    }
    body_2_torque {
      x: 0
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
  }
  time {
    sec: 9
    nsec: 22000000
  }
}
time {
  sec: 9
  nsec: 22000000
}
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2086/has-anybody-gotten-the-contact-sensor-example-to-work-in-a-repo-installed-gazebo-1.5.0/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-26**:
Welp. Installing from source didn't fix it either.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-03-27**:
We had two people at OSRF test each tutorial with the new debs before releasing, so yes we have gotten it to work. Can you paste the full output of what you see when you run `gztopic list`?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-27**:
Updated with the outputs for listing the topics as well as echoing the sensor topic.  Thanks for your attention, sc.

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-03-28**:
can you turn on contact visualization and also make the models transparent (via the View menu) first, then place a sphere on top of the box contact sensor to see if a single contact point visualization appear?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-28**:
Iche, I see one contact point between the box and the sphere.  Also one contact point at every corner of the box that touches the ground.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-28**:
Also, something that may be noteworthy:  When I visualize collisions and I move the box from its original position, an orange square remains on the ground where the box was.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-28**:
When I go to Window -> Topic Visualization and select /gazebo/default/box/link/my_contact, the reported frequency is 0.00 Hz and the bandwidth is 0.00 B/s. What do you guys see here?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-03-28**:
The orange square on the ground represents the collision shape of the ground plane. Can you also `View Contacts` and `View Transparent`?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-28**:
scpeters, that's what "Iche, I see one contact point between the box and the sphere. Also one contact point at every corner of the box that touches the ground." was in regards to.

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-03-29**:
do you see anything if you echo /gazebo/default/physics/contacts ?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-29**:
Iche, I've updated the question to show the start of the output I get from that.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-29**:
Iche, I've updated the question to show the start of the output I get from that.ls

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-03-29**:
On my machine, an active contact sensor will output time-stamps regularly even if there are no contacts to report. This seems like a sensor problem. I just tested the world file in the tutorial and it works fine for me. Are you using debs or a source build?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-29**:
I've tried both.  When the debs didn't work, I installed from source.  "When I go to Window -> Topic Visualization and select /gazebo/default/box/link/my_contact, the reported frequency is 0.00 Hz and the bandwidth is 0.00 B/s. What do you guys see here?"

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-03-29**:
I get about 33 Hz and 800 kB/s.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-03-29**:
Do we know if those are parameters that are set to get the sensor to scan, or are these outputs from the sensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solution:  One needs to add

```
<update_rate>5</update_rate>
```

Between the  and  tags in order to get output on the terminal. The rate "5" can be changed to a different frequency if desired.  I've added this to the tutorial page on the wiki [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/sensors/contact).

---

Originally posted by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) with karma: 175 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0